# How do I stop water entering from where the stack meets the wall in the basment?

Tags: plumbing, walls, basement, flooding

I just bought a house and everything in it is fine. Untill the other day when there was water in the basment. I initially thought it was related to the washer but I found out it was coming from the wall. It was coming from where the stack went out of the basment. It was letting water in from the ground outside the basment. What should I do?

Comment: Any idea where the water outside is coming from?  We don’t know where you are is it rainy?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram of where the water is coming in would help us help you.